# MYSQL Pivots keyword search

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

Hi I have a mysql table that stores users information and each row of the table stores a column of data.

here is a sample of the data

```
dataId    FieldName    FieldData
63        SJMID        CP345223
63        Username     CP345223
63        email        test@test.com
63        Name         Danny Younes
```

The follwoing is the pivot SQL

```
SELECT 
  sso2.dataId, 
  MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'SJM ID', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'SJM ID' , 
  MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'Username', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Username' , 
  MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'Email', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Email',
  MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'Name', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Name'
FROM
  users_table sso2
  GROUP BY sso2.dataId
```

The data is returned to me as follows:

```
dataId    SJMID    Username    Email          Name
63        CP345223 CP345223    test@test.com  Danny Younes
```

When I enter a keyword search into the query, let us say I am searching for the number 522 in each of the fields, the following data is returned:

```
 dataId    SJMID    Username    Email   Name
    63     CP345223 CP345223    NULL    NULL
```

It has only returned the data that it has found a result in and null for everything else. I want the query to return all data for the user. I have been racking my brain over this, I have used Case statements and they seems to work but the performance on a very large database is terrible.

Here is the query with the keyword search

```
SELECT 
      sso2.dataId, 
      MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'SJM ID', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'SJM ID' , 
      MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'Username', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Username' , 
      MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'Email', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Email',
      MAX(IF(sso2.fieldName = 'Name', sso2.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Name'
    FROM
      users_table sso2
    WHERE
      sso2.fieldData COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%522%'
    GROUP BY 
      sso2.dataId
```

So how do I get back all the data for the users where the keyword search has been matched

Thanks in Advance
Danny Younes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you would require to do the `SELF JOIN` based on *dataId*

```
SELECT 
      sso2.dataId, 
      MAX(IF(u.fieldName = 'SJMID', u.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'SJM ID' , 
      MAX(IF(u.fieldName = 'Username', u.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Username' , 
      MAX(IF(u.fieldName = 'Email', u.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Email',
      MAX(IF(u.fieldName = 'Name', u.fieldData, NULL)) AS 'Name'
FROM users_table sso2
INNER JOIN users_table u on u.dataId = sso2.dataId
WHERE sso2.fieldData COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%522%'
GROUP BY sso2.dataId
```